# Битовые операции - алгоритм

Tags: битовые-операции, алгоритм, javascript

Доброго времени суток. 
Встала одна интересная задача.

Есть модели данных. Каждая модель имеет свой битовый идентификатор. Например:

```
User: 0x1
Organization: 0x2
Points: 0x4
.....
```

У любой модели есть список параметров и есть функция getData(flag), которая которая возвращает параметры по битовой маске.

Пример:

```
Model User {
   TYPE: items.TYPE.USER; // 0x1
   getFlags: function() {
      Id: 0x1,
      Name: 0x2,
      Owner: 0x4....
   }
   getData(flag) {
      var dl = this.getFlags();
      var a = {};
      for(var i in dl) {
         var tf = dl[i];
         if(fl & flag) {
            a[i] = this['get' + i]();
         }
      }
      return a;
   }
}

Model Organization { ... }
```

Задача - реализовать функцию, которая по 2-м параметрам (битовым маскам) будет возвращать items-ы с необходимой информацией.
Пример:

```
/**
 * flag - битовая маска модулей
 * info битовая маска информативности по модулям
*/
getItems(flag, info) { ...; return items; };
```

Например, задача выцепить пользователей, но чтобы мне вернулись только их ID и выцепить организации, но только чтобы вернулись имена.

Вопрос - как грамотно составить маску info?

```
flag = User.TYPE + Organization.TYPE
info - ?
```

И встаёт дополнительный вопрос - как в JavaScript можно оперировать большими битовыми флагами ? Большие числа будут сокращаться же :-(

```
<< 100000000000000000111
>> 100000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 4):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то

```
flag = User.TYPE | Organization.TYPE; // не +. Сейчас разницы нет, но на будущее
info = {};
  info[User.TYPE] = User.getFlags().Id | User.getFlags().Name;
  info[Organization.TYPE] = Organization.getFlags().Name;
```

Почему так:

- внезапно в JS нельзя инициализировать объект с переменными в названиях свойств (в кратком формате). Я только что это узнал %)
- Объект формата `type => mask` выбрал потому, что, судя по всему, вы собираетесь работать с большими масками. В другом случае это может быть простой массив масок (`(User.TYPE << 16) | User.getFlags().Id`) с разбором в функции.

По второй части вопроса - динамическая типизация JS + разноразрядность осей съест вам голову. Для работы с "большими масками" лучше использовать массивы, а при проверке передавать еще смещения Т.е. маска в 64 бита - это массив 2 х int32

```
var mask64 = [ 0x00020000, 0x00200080 ];
```

, а проверка 62-го бита - это

```
test(0x00000002 /*30-й бит*/ , 1/* смещение в 32 бит */)
```

Как-то так вроде.

Comment: Спасибо. Да, не +, а | - это правильно :-)
Завтра гляну, посмотрим что получится :)

Comment: @Станислав Комар, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).